# Running Node server takes over entire server and makes other project directory inaccessible, even with node-http-proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am transitioning a traditional LAMP-stack app to a NodeJS equivalent. However, there are multiple projects on the dev server, all shared between different teams. My app files exist in `/projects/1/` directory, but as soon as I browse `cd` into the directory and hit `npm start`, the app runs on `http://dev.test.com:3000`. In some cases (randomly), going to `http://dev.test.com` automatically begins to redirect to the node app on port 3000, making it impossible for any team member to access their project. What I would like is that when I start the server, it runs just inside the `/projects/1/` directory. It doesn't matter whether it runs in `http://test.dev.com:3000/projects/1/` or `http://test.dev.com/projects/1/`, but I need it to run inside that directory, not take over the entire server.

I discussed this in the JavaScript room and was recommended to look into reverse proxies. Upon researching, I discovered [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) and installed it. But now, `http://dev.test.com:3000`, refuses to load altogether, meaning I went one step back instead of forward.

Here is `routes/index.js`:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var httpProxy = require("http-proxy");
var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

router.get("/projects/1/*", function(req, res) {
  apiProxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://dev.test.com:3000' });
});

router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("hi");
});

module.exports = router;
```

I can see "hi" in the console, but the page is forever loading. I'd be happy to provide more code/info if need be.

Comment: As far as the request hanging, you're never ending it.  Try calling `req.status(200).end()` in the `.get('/'` call.

Comment: node doesn't really have a concept of url folders, it takes over the whole port. you need to stop the redirect to 3000 from 80 on the root. you can use an apache redirect if needed, but just keep the port separated and things will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

An http server like node.js does not "run on a directory".  It runs on a particular port at a particular IP address and it runs continually and it handles ALL traffic sent to that port on that server's IP address.  So, if your node.js server is running on port 3000, then ALL traffic regardless of path that is directed to port 3000 on that server will go to your node.js app.

You could run a proxy in front of the server (there are many that will work, but nginx is one common one) that would route a given request to a different port (and thus to a different actual server process) based on the path, but you cannot fix your problem by just changing your node.js server alone.

node.js does not work like some other technologies that could work by directory because node.js has a continually running server that handles all incoming traffic to a given port.

If you are attempting to use a proxy in the way described above and it is not working, then you likely do not have the proxy configured correctly and you should probably ask a very detailed question about how to set it up correctly and show exactly what configuration you are using.